# The Rising Roar of Registration

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

Today's riddle is split into two. Find out what I am.

<sub>P.S. This riddle works much better when told aloud, so some spelling has been adjusted to how you would hear it, and it is not necessarily the word that is actually there.</sub>

> I am needed to break bread,
> No edge used for me to spread.
>
> To dance through the forest with song and grace,
> Ever to become a tasty snack that once had a face.

Second Part:

> Regarded as the primary, the protag, or the first,
> Now as the crown of a beast, who hungers and thirsts.
>
> Even some people, are considered to have me,
> To clarify that which is most important you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Domain.

Except

> It is split between two parts of the puzzle to be do-main.

I am needed to break bread,
No edge used for me to spread.

> Dough

To dance through the forest with song and grace,
Ever to become a tasty snack that once had a face.

> Doe as in a dear, and you can eat it.

Second Part:

Regarded as the primary, the protag, or the first,

> Main

Now as the crown of a beast, who hungers and thirsts.

> Mane of a lion.

Even some people, are considered to have me,

> Bushy hair.

To clarify that which is most important you see.

> The "main" thing

Hidden hint

> INTERNET acrostic

Title

> You register a domain name for a website.

Comment: Your answer is right, but some of the hints are off (mostly the second part). Each part of the riddle refers specifically to one part of the answer. The first part is rot13(qb) and the second part rot13(znva). You should be able to get the clues based on that.

Comment: Any better @Joe-You-Know?

Comment: A little better. The second part of the first series of the riddle is referring to a rot13(qbr, n srznyr qrre. Iravfba vf dhvgr gnfgl, jbhyqa'g lbh nterr?)